# Python keeping socket alive?

Tags: python, sockets, loops, tcp, connection

Hey I'm working on a python project using sockets. Basically I want to loop a connection to a host for user input. Here is what I'm trying:

```
while True:
    sock.connect((host, port))
    inputstring = " > "
    userInput = raw_input(inputstring)
    sock.send(userInput + '\r\n\r\n')
    recvdata = sock.recv(socksize)
    print(recvdata)
```

But when I loop the socket and try connecting to localhost on port 80 I get an error saying the transport endpoint is still connected or something like that. How can I eliminate that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `connect` outside the `while` loop. You only need to connect once.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `sock.connect` outside of your `while True`.

Comment: Aye because you are not closing that socket, and yet trying to connect to it over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to connect to the host once, then you can run your loop. Try:

```
sock.connect((host, port))
while True:
    inputstring = " > "
    # etc
```

If the body of your loop were to `sock.close()`, you would need to `.connect()` again at the top of the loop. But you probably don't want to disconnect and reconnect each time, so do the above.