# Having trouble keeping socket alive Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm trying to create a client/server console game, but I'm having trouble keeping the socket alive, it seems to be closing before I've called `close()` and I can't figure out why.

I've read the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201388/python-keeping-socket-alive) but I have called `connect()` outside of the while loop since the logic of that already made sense to me before I attempted to run it, but I'm still getting the error from the server shell though:

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

<s>So far I'm not getting an error on the client shell, it just exits running right after launching which is also when the server error occurs.</s>

After fixing mistakes noted in the comments, the client now also shows an error stating that `connected` is undefined when attempting to start the while loop but should be since `Connect()` is run before entering the loop which should have set `connected = True` thus the loop should run but does not. I doubt this is related to the server issue at all, but what maybe the problem here?

I'll put the code for both below:

**Client**

```
import socket

def GetData():
    data = s.recv(1000).decode()
    if (data == "closing"):
        connected = False
    else:
        print(data)

def SendData():
    tdata = input("")
    s.send(data.encode())


def Connect():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 2222))
    connected = True


global connected
Connect()

while (connected == True):
    GetData()
    if (connected == False):
        s.close()
        break
    SendData()
```

**Server**

```
import socket
import random

def TheMainGame():
    print ("started TheMainGame")  # Remove after debug
    def within(val, goal):
        print ("Runing 'within' function")  # Remove after debug
        i = abs(val - goal)
        if (i <= 5):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def Guess():
        print ("Running 'Guess' function")  # Remove after debug
        while True:
            print ("Entered while loop")  # Remove after debug
            data = "What is your guess?"
            c.send(data.encode())
            print ("Sent data")  # Remove after debug
            t = c.recv(1000).decode()
            print ("Got data")  # Remove after debug
            if (t == x):
                data = "Correct!"
                c.send(data.encode())
                data = "closing"
                c.send(data.encode())
                c.close()
                break
            elif (within(t,x) == True):
                data = "You're close!"
                c.send(data.encode())
            elif (within(t,x) == False):
                data = "Try again"
                c.send(data.encode())
            else:
                data = "There was an error computing the value"
                c.send(data.encode())
                c.close()
                break

    x = random.randrange(1, 20, 1)
    Guess()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 2222))
s.listen(5)
global data
while True:
    (c,a) = s.accept()
    print("Received connection from", a)  # Remove after debug
    data = "Hello %s" %a[0]  # Remove after debug
    c.send(data.encode())  # Remove after debug
    TheMainGame()
```

The error in the server shell relates to line 19 which is why the server attempts to ask the client the question, which is also the second time it attempts to send data to the client but the attempt never successfully happens, which is why I think the socket is being closed even though I never told it to anywhere before that point since it hasn't even been able to check if `t == x`. What is causing the socket to close?

Comment: You've misspelled `connected` in `Connect()` in your client code. Also, if you intend to assign to a global variable, you must use the `global` keyword with the variable name in the function scope.

Comment: @JoelCornett Oh, so I did! After fixing that, I made `connected` global (I'll edit my question to reflect the change) and now I'm getting an error in the client too at the while loop stating `connected` is not defined, but it should be since I ran `Connect()` which would set it to `True` before entering the loop...

Comment: @JoelCornett Problem is now solved, thank you for helping! It would have been solved even quicker if I'd brushed up my knowledge on how global vars work. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mis-using global in the client.

in the main body you have `global connected`. This is incorrect.

Instead, at the top of the file put:

```
import socket
connected = False
```

Then, in the Connect function, pull in the global scoped variable:

```
def Connect():
    global connected
    ...
```

The keyword `global` is to tell a function to use a variable from the global scope, not to define them.

Note:
There are other errors in this code which you will need to look at and address.

1. You've done the same in server.py
2. You're trying to reference socket `s` in the `GetData` and `SendData` functions but `s` is local to within the connect function only (meaning that the connection will drop once the function exists.

Comment: Oh, that's how global works! Thank you for clarifying, I fix up the code now.

Comment: Thank you! It works! Now I just have logic errors I need to brush up on. Many thanks.